# Create custom iterator with step functionality

Tags: python

I have a pdf in which I create page numbers for a table of content. Some topics in a pdf overlaps into multiple pages for that I need to use steps while others stay on one page.

I have created a custom iterator like this:

```
class IndexPageCounter:
    """
        Used to create index page counter for a table of content
    """

    def __iter__(self):
        self.num = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self, step=1):
        num = self.num
        self.num += step
        return num
```

and call it like this:

```
obj = iter(IndexPageCounter())
print(next(obj)) # this works fine
print(next(obj, step=2) # this doesn't work
# above line gives TypeError: next() takes no keyword arguments
```

I tried looking it up but I don't see any example of creating a custom iterator with step.

Edit:

I can't pass the value of step in the constructor as the value of the step is not constant.

Comment: `next` doesn't take any kwargs. Pass the step as a constructor argument (similar to how `range` works), or use a different method.

Comment: @SuperStormer Why is it downvoted ? The value of step is not constant I can't pass it in constructor

Comment: then it's not suited for the iterator protocol - just use a custom method instead.

Comment: @SuperStormer I don't see a reason of downvoting this question

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I fixed it by creating a separate function in the class check my answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the built in `next()` fn doesn’t have a steps kwarg. I think you can approach this problem with a generator instead though. Something like:

```py
def next_index_page(step=1):
  last_page = 25
  index = 1 # first page is 1 
  while index <= last_page:
    yield index 
    index += step
```

If you need this to be a custom iterator class, consider putting the logic for calculating step into `__next__` so that you don’t need to specify step from the calling code.

Something like

```py
class IndexIter:
  def __init__(self, start_page=1):
    self.current_index = start_page

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    self.current_index = self.get_next_index_page()
    return current_index

  def get_next_index_page(self):
    # logic for getting next index
```

**Note:**
I would strongly suggest designing your code so that the logic for something like `get_next_index_page()` is in the generator or the custom iterator's `__next__()` method. This is because you want your iterator to behave like an iterator (i.e. you can call `next()` or loop through it). If you don't have this your example would be better served with a simple variable that you increment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have fixed it by creating a separate function, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a separate function `get_next` like this:

```
class IndexPageCounter:
    """
        Used to create index page counter for a table of content
    """

    def __iter__(self):
        self.num = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        num = self.num
        self.num += 1
        return num

    def get_next(self, step=1):
       for _ in range(0, step):
          self.__next__()
       return self.num
```

and call it like this:

```
obj = iter(IndexPageCounter())
print(obj.get_next()) # works
print(obj.get_next(step=2)) # works too
```

Comment: If I was reviewing this code I'd suggest not using an iter at all if you're just going to add a `get_next` method. In this example you essentially have a class wrapping an integer variable.